# Error Could not find or load main class testing (Java)

Tags: java

// Error : Could not find or load main class
  I have created on file with name Foo.java and Bar.java both files are in different package . They compiled successfully but  i am unable to execute program

```
package demo;
public class Foo
{
   protected int result=20;
   int other=25;
}
```

second file : Bar.java

```
package testing;
import demo.Foo;
public class Bar extends Foo
{
 private int sum=10;
   public void Info()
    {
   sum+=result;
 System.out.println(sum);
    }
 public static void main(String[] args)
   {
     Bar b=new Bar();
     b.Info();
   }

}
```

To compile i have used following commands :

```
  javac -d . Foo.java
  javac -d . Bar.java
  cd testing
  java Bar
  Error Could not find or load main class testing (Java)
```

[This is the error i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hndTd.png)

Error Could not find or load main class testing (Java)

Comment: Why are you changing you directory? Just run.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you should use `javac -cp . Foo.java`. (Same for Bar)
Then you should start your your program wtih `java Foo`

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things you can have a look.

1. Whether your class Foo and Bar are in system classpath.
2. Whether your class Foo and Bar are under the package folders as a hierarchy.

For example Foo should be under folder demo and Bar should be under folder testing.

cheers,

Saurav

Answer (score 0):

You only need to do:

```
javac -d . Foo.java
javac -d . Bar.java
java testing.Bar
```

Answer (score 0):

The class loader does not find the Foo class and because of that it cannot load Bar (which depends on Foo)

In your case I would run it as Martín Muñoz del Río stated in his answer

> You only need to do:
>
> javac -d . Foo.java
>
> javac -d . Bar.java
>
> java testing.Bar